# Need help finding specific characters with regex - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, forms, validation

I'm trying to make a validation for phone numbers, I am trying to make it so regex filters certain characters out of the string so it can then be checked, I need ( ) - and a space to be filtered out, I figured i would have to use the replace() method but i find regex really confusing due to the masses of characters given on examples.

This is what i figured I would have to do to filter them out, but i don't know what to enter in the / / area:

```
var Telephone           = document.forms["OrderForm"]["Telephone"].value;
var TelephoneException  = Telephone.replace(/[Characters "()- " here]/, "");
```

Comment: If you only want the string to contains numbers. `Telephone.replace(/[^\d]/g,"");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
Telephone.replace(/[\(\)\- ]/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the parenthesis and minus because they part of the regex syntax. Also add a `g` at the end to make sure this replaces all occurrences:

```
Telephone.replace(/[\(\)- ]/g, "");
```